# Implement the Clone trait for a struct that holds a generic ref to a path via AsRef(Path)

Tags: rust, trait-bounds

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
pub struct MyConfig<P>
{
    // Path to file
    pub file_path: P,
    // Other settings
    pub setting1: u8,
    // [...]
}

impl <P: AsRef<Path> + std::fmt::Debug> MyConfig<P>
{
    pub fn with_path(file_path:: P) -> Result<Self>
    {
        MyConfig
        {
            file_path,
            setting1: 1
        }
    }
}
```

I need a way to clone that config object. I can't just `#[derive(Clone)]`, because of the `P` trait bound. I tried implementing `Clone` manually, but I can't find a way to make a generic copy/clone of the `file_path` property. For example, why does this not work:

```
impl <P: AsRef<Path> + std::fmt::Debug> Clone for MyConfig<P>
{
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self { file_path: Path::new(self.file_path.as_ref().file_name()),
               setting1: self.setting1.clone(),
            }
    }
}
```

I'm quite new to Rust, so maybe this is a really dumb question (or implementation), but I'm really at my wits' end with this - seemingly trivial - problem!

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply requiring `P: Clone`? Alternatively, if you're trying to use `P: AsRef<Path>` to avoid always allocating memory for a `PathBuf`, and you have cases where you can't always use `&'a Path`, then you could potentially use `Cow<'a, Path>` instead

Comment: I don't think `P: Clone` will be useful here because a bunch of the types implementing `AsRef<Path>` aren't `Clone` due to being unsized (e.g., `str`, `Path`). `ToOwned` is probably the more useful trait bound on `P` and may well be the correct trait to implement for `MyConfig`.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not 100% sure I understand what `AsRef(Path)` actually does - I copied that from some example code of the library I'm passing the `file_path` into. As I always get the file_path from the command line exactly once, I suppose it makes sense to pass it as ref not clone? What would happen if I say `<P: AsRef(Path) + Clone + Debug>`? Is that a paradox?

Comment: You can simply derive `Clone`. It will add an implicit `P: Clone` trait bound for the `Clone` implementation, i.e. you can only clone your struct if `P: Clone`. However, from you last comment it sounds like you'd rather want to use `file_path: PathBuf`. The generic struct doesn't help you here, and using an owned `PathBuf` will make everything much easier for you.

Comment: @BallpointBen But they also can't be used with this struct. A reference to them can, but obviously it is `Clone`.

Comment: If you don't understand this code, perhaps you don't need this complexity - consider replacing the  `AsRef<Path>` with a simple `&Path` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of `AsRef<Path>` is to make your *public functions* more usable, so you can invoke them with values of types `&str`, `String`, `&Path`, and `PathBuf`. But there is no reason to *hold* a value so generic. This applies doubly if you're a novice and unsure of what `AsRef<Path>` does to begin with - in that case, accept `AsRef<Path>` in the public API, and immediately convert it to `PathBuf`:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct MyConfig {
    // Path to file
    pub file_path: PathBuf,
    // Other settings
    pub setting1: u8,
    // [...]
}

impl MyConfig {
    pub fn with_path(file_path: impl AsRef<Path>) -> Self {
        MyConfig {
            file_path: file_path.as_ref().to_owned(),
            setting1: 1,
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e5e94e73fdad0aa565c7087916c38168)

This way you get a fully owned object that can derive `Clone` and `Debug`.

Remark for advanced usage: When you unconditionally create `PathBuf`, you can alternatively accept `file_path: impl Into<PathBuf>`, and create the pathbuf with `file_path.into()`. This will accept a similar choice of types like `AsRef<Path>` does, but will avoid a reallocation if the caller passes an owned `String` or `PathBuf`. This technique is used e.g. by the [fs_err crate](https://docs.rs/fs-err/latest/fs_err/struct.File.html#method.open) to avoid unnecessary allocation.

Comment: If you want to convert the parameter to a `PathBuf`, it might be better to accept `Into<PathBuf>` rather than `AsRef<Path>`. It's at least as generic, but avoids a memory allocation in some cases, e.g. if the type passed in is `String`, `OsString`, `PathBuf` or `Box<Path>`. Using `AsRef<Path>` always requires a memory allocation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I agree, but the answer is intentionally written to build on the OP's existing knowledge of `AsRef<Path>`, which is massively used in the standard library. The mandatory allocation is very likely a non-issue for this kind of object.

Comment: I wasn't asking you to change your answer. I just meant to add additional information, probably aimed at a more advnaced audience than your answer.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful - I had seen this "trait requirement for function parameters" syntax somewhere before, but now I get how to use it. I suppose the `file_path.as_ref().to_owned()` is a way to "regularize" &str, String, &Path etc?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Understood, but I still thinks it makes sense to include the info in the answer. StackOverflow comments are sometimes nuked without notice, and they're not supposed to contain important info. I've now added a remark to the answer to that effect.

Comment: @DaGaMs That's a good way to look at it, yes. In fact, regularization is fully done by `.as_ref()` which gives you `&Path`. Since you want to create an owned PathBuf object, the added `.to_owned()` accomplishes that - but at that point the type is concrete and no longer generic.

Comment: There is some (rare) usage for `AsRef<Path>` is a field. if you want to store that struct in another struct, then perhaps you don't want `&Path` because you don't want the lifetime, and you don't want `PathBuf` because this forces an allocation on the user.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman After thinking about this, I'm not sure `AsRef<Path>` can be used to get rid of the lifetime. To use `AsRef<Path>` in a field, you have to make your struct generic over a `T: AsRef<Path>` and use the `T` as the type of the field. The `T` generic carries a hidden lifetime, e.g. you can't send such a struct to a thread, unless you add `T: Send + 'static`. If you were able to truly get rid of a lifetime like that, Rust's type system would be unsound. Maybe I didn't understand correctly what you meant by getting rid of the lifetime?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, but if you use it with `PathBuf` you don't have a lifetime. You can chose between having a lifetime or allocating.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I see, you were referring to the _user_, not the implementer of `MyConfig`, who would have a choice between `MyConfig<PathBuf>` (no lifetime, owned/allocated `file_path`) and `MyConfig<&'a Path>` (lifetime, borrowed `file_path`).

Answer (score 1):

`AsRef` is a trait meant for types that encapsulate a reference to an underlying object. For example, `AsRef<Path>` is implemented by `&Path`, `PathBuf`, `Rc<Path>`, `Arc<Path>`, and others. It's convenient when you don't care whether a type is borrowed or owned.

However, `AsRef<T>` is not necessarily cloneable: `&mut T` isn't, for example.

You can require that your `P` implements `Clone` for your structure to implement `Clone`, which will solve your immediate compile error:

```
impl <P: AsRef<Path> + std::fmt::Debug + Clone> Clone for MyConfig<P>
```

But keep in mind that if `P` is a reference, its clone will be as well. Clones of `MyConfig` will just hold copies of the reference without ownership. This may or may not be what you want. Since `clone()` requires that you return `Self` - the structure with the same generic parameters as the one being cloned, you can't get around that with the standard `Clone` trait, and will have to implement such "deep copying" with either a different method or trait.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful answer, too. I indeed "fixed" my compilation error by adding `Clone` to the trait bounds (I hope that's correct terminology), and it works because under the hood  I only ever use `PathBuf`s that were created from command line arguments and thus, presumably, have a "static" lifetime. I'll probably go with a refactor as suggested in the other answer...